# Discrepant Google Analytics Data In PowerBI When Using Built In Connector

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi

I was tasked with creating multiple PowerBI reports and dashboards that encompass our website data from Google Analytics (GA). I started with our primary website, and used the built in custom connector from PowerBI to consume this data. This connector, however, is "supported" by Google, and I'm having some issues with the data.

[Google Analytics Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjDUw.png)

[PowerBI Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ventg.png)

As you can see in these two screenshots, some of the data matches, and some of it does not. The time frame for both screenshots show for Nov. 2019. I understand there may be a little bit of data discrepancy; however, the custom connector in PowerBI does not allow for me to show the unique users. This is one of the most important attributes to any websites as it is more accurate showing how many individuals are actually visiting your website due to the cookies on their machine. Another big data issue I noticed is the bounce rate is almost twice as much as the actual bounce rate in GA.

Is there any way to bring in the Unique User and Bounce Rate metric accurately? The marketing team currently uses DashThis, and it shows this data, so I know it's possible- I just don't know how it's being done.

Comment: Did you mean "unsupported" by Google?

Comment: Honestly, most of what Google supports is unsupported anyway...but yes and no. I know the connector itself was made by Microsoft, but the GA Core API is "supported" by Google. I believe it's something with their Core API, though.

Answer (score 0):

So Power bi's connector for google analytics has a sampling issue and an API Calls limit. The standard limitations and quotas for Google Analytics API requests are documented in Limits and Quotas on API Requests. However, Power BI Desktop and Power BI service allow you to use the following enhanced number of queries.

Queries per day: 1,500,000, Queries per 100 seconds: 4,000

Might be better to connect Google analytics to a data warehouse such as Google BigQuery, which will help you get access to historical data that you won't be able to get with Power bi's connector. I'd suggest using a third-party connector.